# Print weekdays and check if a date exists for this weekday

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, momentjs

I have an array of dates

```
date_array = ["date1", "date2", "date3"]
```

I would like to print

```
Tuesday: Yes
Wednesday: No
Thursday: No
Friday: Yes
Saturday: No
Sunday: Yes
```

where Yes and No depends on whether there is a date in `date_array` on this weekday in the current week and the order of the weekdays should start from today's weekday.

I am using `moment` where the weekday number can be formatted with `e`, so I get the number of today's weekday with `moment().format('e')`. Alternatively, it could be with `moment().day()` where sunday=0.

I guess I could do something like

```js
// Existing dates
var dates = [moment(), moment().add(3, 'days'), moment().add(5, 'days')]

// All weekdays to print
var weekdays = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

// Reorder
var today_weekday = moment().day()
var weekdays_reordered = weekdays.splice(today_weekday).concat(weekdays)

// Print
weekdays_reordered.map((weekday, i) => {
  console.log(weekday + ': ' + (dates.some(date => date.day() === i) ? 'Yes' : 'No'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

But I'm not sure how exactly to make it work.

Comment: What is `existingDates`?

Comment: `moment()` does not return a Date, it returns a moment object. Do you have an array of Dates or moments?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need to print every day from current day until the end of the week, i.e. Sunday? Then, you need to set `today_weekday` as `moment().day() - 1` (because of the indices), and then exit the loop when you get to Monday (changed it from `map()` to a `for()`, because you can't break out of map). Lastly, compare the date formated to `dddd` (the weekday name) to the current weekday element in the loop. Something like this:

```js
var dates = [moment(), moment().add(4, 'days'), moment().add(5, 'days')]

// All weekdays to print
var weekdays = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

// Reorder
var today_weekday = moment().day() - 1;
var weekdays_reordered = weekdays.splice(today_weekday).concat(weekdays)

for(var i = 0; i < weekdays_reordered.length; i++) {
    var weekday = weekdays_reordered[i];
        if (weekday === "Monday" && i !== 0) break;
    console.log(weekday + ': ' + (dates.some(date => date.format("dddd") === weekday) ? 'Yes' : 'No'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is almost what I need! The problem is that I would like to be able to change the weekdays array to different names, so I am wondering if it's possible to use the weekday number instead of the comparison using `date.format('dddd')`?

Comment: You could then compare `date.day()` or `date.weekday()` to the index of the current element. Be careful with the indices though, read the docs to see if for moment.js the week starts on sunday or monday, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have an array of dates and not moment objects, you can create a date for today then check if the same date is in the array. Then step through the days of the week. Testing for date equality is a little tricky but if they are all created for say 00:00:00 then you can just check the time value.

```js
var base = new Date();
base.setHours(0,0,0,0);

var seed = new Date(+base);
// Array of dates for today, today + 2 days, today + 4 days
var dates = [new Date(seed),
  new Date(seed.setDate(seed.getDate() + 2)),
  new Date(seed.setDate(seed.getDate() + 2))
];

// Test 7 days, starting from today
for (var i=7; i; --i) {
  // Get weekday name in host default language
  var s = base.toLocaleString(undefined, {weekday:'long'}) + ': ';
  // See if there's a matching date
  s += dates.find(d=>+d == +base)? 'Yes':'No';
  // Add 1 to the date
  base.setDate(base.getDate() + 1);
  // Do something with the result
  console.log(s);
}
```

The above requires [*Array.prototype.find*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-array.prototype.find), there's a [polyfill on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) if required. You may need to define a different comparison (predicate) function if you want to compare only date without the time.

Comment: It would be handy if down voters would explain their vote. If they did, the answer could be improved or deleted if inappropriate.